# How to access properties of AssetLoadedFunc in LoadAssets? TypeScript? Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, dom-events

I am calling  `this.AssetLoadedFunc` in `LoadAssets(callback, user_data)`

```
 LoadAssets(callback, user_data) {
      this.glg.LoadWidgetFromURL("assets/Js/scrollbar_h.g", null,
          this.AssetLoaded,
          {
            name: "scrollbar_h", callback: callback,
            user_data: user_data
          });  
      }

AssetLoaded(glg_object, data) {
      if (data.name == "scrollbar_h") {
          if (glg_object != null)
            glg_object.SetResourceObject("$config/GlgHScrollbar", glg_object);
        }
        else
          console.error("Unexpected asset name");

         if (!this.AssetLoaded.num_loaded )
          this.AssetLoaded.num_loaded = 1;
        else
          ++this.AssetLoaded.num_loaded;
      }
```

**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property**

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'AssetLoaded' of null
>           at AssetLoadedFunc (app.component.ts:540)

Comment: AssetLoadedFunc needs two arguments, you're not passing them.

Comment: function get called but AssetLoaded is null @Ramesh

Comment: you need to bind context `this.AssetLoadedFunc.bind(this)` for third argument of LoadWidgetFromURL  method

Answer (score 1):

Method `AssetLoadedFunc` is executed with different execution  context and can not receive access to `AssetLoaded` property with `this.AssetLoaded` expression. You could bind context for AssetLoadedFunc and use code like that:

```
LoadAssets(callback, user_data) {
      this.glg.LoadWidgetFromURL("assets/Js/scrollbar_h.g", null,
          this.AssetLoadedFunc.bind(this),
          {
            name: "scrollbar_h", callback: callback,
            user_data: user_data
          });  
      }
      AssetLoaded: any = { num_loaded: null }
      AssetLoadedFunc(glg_object, data) {
        if (data.name == "scrollbar_h") {
          if (glg_object != null)
            glg_object.SetResourceObject("$config/GlgHScrollbar", glg_object);
        }
        else
          console.error("Unexpected asset name");

         if (!this.AssetLoaded.num_loaded )
          this.AssetLoaded.num_loaded = 1;
        else
          ++this.AssetLoaded.num_loaded;
      }
```